# Predict Location coordinates from time data

Tags: matlab, location, octave, predict

I have data consisting of time (sec) in the x-axis and location (x,y,z) in the y-axis. I want to be able to predict location (x,y,z) using time (sec). What machine learning algorithm can I use? How can I accomplish this in Matlab/Octave?

Specifically, I have the following data

```
 Time            Location

`0`       `[470 491 0]`


`2`      [174 281 5]


70.29  [174 281 0]


72.29  [490 257 2]
```

How do I predict location from time?

I appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

too few datapoints, you can always use linear interpolation

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am able to predict the location within the time range using the interp1 (interpolation) command. If I were to predict outside the time range, what is the command for extrapolation?Or if regression can take care of this, how does regression predict 3D data such as location (x,y,z)?